# In perl, can HEREIS notation be used inside hash initialization?

Tags: perl, hash, initialization

I am trying to initialize a hash like this:

```
use strict;

my %hash =
(
    key => <<END;
abc
def
END
    ,
    another_key => 17
);
```

When I run perl -cw on this code, I get the error 'syntax error at hash-initialize-test.pl line 5, near ";"'.

Is there a way to use HEREIS notation (such as `<<END;`) within hash initialization? If not, why not?

There are several simple workarounds, but I like to use HEREIS notation for multi-line strings because it is elegant and avoids introducing unnecessary variables.

Comment: I tried choroba's solution and it worked. Previously, I had always used a semi-colon within HEREIS notation and had never terminated the end-quote with a comma, but it makes sense in this case because the key-value pair within the hash initialization ends with a comma. Thanks!

Comment: It is usually called a [**HEREDOC**](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=perldoc+heredoc). ( don't change the question as people searching for hereis need to be able to find the information too )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the semicolon. There is no statement end.

```
my %hash = ( key => <<'END',
abc
def
END
             another_key => 17,
           );
```